# Android override accessibility "double tap to activate"

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have a refresh button on my screen which TalkBack should announce as "Refresh button, refreshes the page". It shouldn't announce "double tap to activate".

I'm using

```
contentDescription="refresh"
```

and a custom accessibility delegate.

Below is the custom accessibility delegate:

```
class CustomClickAccessibilityDelegate(private val clickDescription: String) : View AccessibilityDelegate {

  override fun onInitialiseAccessibilityNodeInfo(host: View?, info: AccessibilityNodeInfo?) {
    super.onInitialiseAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
    val customClick = AccessibilityNodeInfo.AccessibilityAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_CLICK, clickDescription)
    info?.addAction(customClick)
  }
}
```

With `contentDescription="refresh"`, and the custom accessibility `delegate` taking "refreshes the page", announcement reads "refresh button. Double tap to refreshes the page" while I need it to announce "refresh button, refreshes the page". Is there a way to prevent TalkBack from saying "double tap to".

Answer (score 0):

To achieve something close to this, you want to replace the action description of the component:

```
/**
 * renames the "activate" portion of the announcement from "double tap to activate"
 * @param descriptionResourceId: The string resource - should be translated
 *
 * example usage:
 * val refreshButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.refresh_button)
 * refreshButton.renameClickAction(R.string.action_refresh)
 *
 * reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#understandable-actions
 */
fun Button.renameClickAction(@StringRes descriptionResourceId: Int) {
    ViewCompat.replaceAccessibilityAction(
        this,
        AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.AccessibilityActionCompat.ACTION_CLICK,
        // Announcement read by TalkBack to surface this action
        getText(descriptionResourceId),
        null
    )
}
```

I made it an extension function, but the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#understandable-actions) demonstrates that this is not necessary. It is worth noting that screen reader users who use different languages may be left out as a result.

It's worth pointing out that the "double tap to" portion is part of TalkBack, and indicates the gestures that are available to users (like if there are addition actions, state, etc) - If you want to take that away you are moving away from a consistent experience for users, and it may be difficult for them to use your app. [Other portions of the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#accessibility-actions) also infer that we should be adding *more* actions, not removing them

> It is important to allow users of accessibility services to easily perform all user flows within your app. For example, if a user can swipe on an item in a list, this action can also be exposed to Accessibility services so users have an alternative way to complete the same user flow.

By removing the announcement for "Double tap to ..." how will folks know that there are actions available? The main WCAG regression you would be introducing is that of Success Criterion 3.2.4: [Consistent navigation](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/consistent-identification):

> Components that have the same functionality within a set of [Activities] are identified consistently.

What makes this button so unique that users should not know that they can activate it the same way as other buttons? Perhaps I am misunderstanding the reason for removing this requirement, but from the question it seems a little odd to require it's removal.